# ESAPI + Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, esapi

I want to implement the ESAPI in spring-mvc for XSS. We have to use the ESAPI validator API to implement it. The ESAPI property holds the acceptable value for each form field.

How should the configuration look like to use the ESAPI within Spring MVC?

Please suggest the solution.